# How to build a react-native app for sharing for test without having local dependency

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, ios-app-group

I am new to react-native app development. I wanted to know how can a developed app be shared between other developers without having a local dependency. Is an apple developer account needed for a test build to be shared in ios as well? How can the test build be created?. I wanted the build to be created and downloaded on any ios device or android for testing purpose and without having depending any of the local code changes.So the build downloaded should not get updated after any code change done after that.

Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share a release build for **Android** please follow this guide [**Generating Signed APK**](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html).

But for **iOS** you gonna need a Apple Developer account, I don't know the whole process exactly.

Comment: So a .ipa file cannot be created without a apple developer account ?

Comment: @SnehaS probably yes, it can't be created without a developer account.